# change the position of labels

Tags: jquery, css, html, jakarta-ee

i'am working in an application with JAVAEE and i was wondering if i could do the following thing.
in my controller i get some list that contains string

```
          <c:forEach var='var' items='${args}' varStatus="loop">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="tc" id="id${loop.index}">
          <span class="labels"> ${var}</span>
          </label><br/>
          </c:forEach>
```

my problem is the way i get thoses values displayed , i get something like that :
LABEL 
LABEL
LABEL
LABEL
LABEL
LABEL
the problem is my resultat are over 100 , i just need some idea or code that could help do something like that:
Label    label    label
label    label    label
label    label    label
label    label    label

i can display all my data in 3 columns or some special number of columns that will allow me to have a good view and not a long list.
thanks.

Comment: Just don't emit the `<br/>` after each row.